# Calling node.js from a .bat file and outputting response to a text file

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I need to execute a node.js file from a .bat file, and direct the response to a file. Here is my .bat file:

start cmd.exe /k node "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyFolder\MyNodeFile.js" createOrder >output.txt

The MyNodeFile.js file contains a function createOrder.

This works, that  is, a command prompt window opens, the function executes correctly, and the response is displayed in the command prompt window. An output.txt file is created, but is empty. What change do I need to make to direct the response to the text file?

Comment: What happens if you use `start "" cmd.exe /k "node "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyFolder\MyNodeFile.js" createOrder >output.txt"`?

Comment: Doesn't work, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: What doesn't work? This is a technical site, 'doesn't work' does not provide us sufficient information to determine what exactly is happening.

Comment: "Doesn't work" in this case = same result as without the ""

Comment: So you're still getting the response displayed in the Command Prompt window, and an empty output.txt! Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure..

Comment: What happens if you manually open a Command Prompt window, and in it, type `node "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyFolder\MyNodeFile.js" createOrder >output.txt`, and press `[ENTER]`? Also what happens if you change my previously suggested line to `start "" cmd.exe /k "node "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyFolder\MyNodeFile.js" createOrder >output.txt 2>&1"`?